# saving a image along with file name into a access database c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a c# application that is conected to a access database, I am then using a openfiledialog to find a image and then display details about this, I then want to save this to the database. But when i try to do this i get a error saying its too big. So what is the way around this? I want the file path saved and then be able to view it later in my main window.

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataRow drNewRow = m_dtMedia.NewRow();
        drNewRow["File_Path"] = textBox1.Text;
        drNewRow["Subject"] = textBox2.Text;
        drNewRow["Title"] = textBox3.Text;
        drNewRow["Keyword_Search"] = textBox4.Text;
        drNewRow["MediaType"] = textBox5.Text;
        m_dtMedia.Rows.Add(drNewRow);

        m_daDataAdapter.Update(m_dtMedia);
        m_rowPosition = m_dtMedia.Rows.Count - 1;
        this.ShowCurrentRecord();
        this.Close();
```

this works as i have tried typing in just letters and it will save and update the database, saving images on the other hand doesnt.

The error message

OLeDb exception was upheld

The field is too small to accept the amount of data you attempted to add.  Try inserting or pasting less data.

Comment: what error message did you get?

Comment: Check the maximum lengths of your columns in Access. And you know this just stores the filename in the database, not the image itself, right?

Comment: how would i store the image in the database? this is what i want to do.

Answer (score 2):

[Uploading and Downloading BLOBs to Microsoft Access](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16851/Uploading-and-Downloading-BLOBs-to-Microsoft-Acces) This will explain you how to store image in Access database.

> Microsoft Access stores BLOB data in the a field with an OLE Object
>   data type. If you are
>   creating the table from a SQL statement, the data type is IMAGE
>   (similar to SQL Server).

For example

```
CREATE TABLE File (
     FileName VARCHAR(255),
     Size INT,
     Type VARCHAR(255),
     DateUploaded DATETIME,
     File IMAGE,
     CONSTRAINT File_PK PRIMARY KEY(FileName)
)
```

Comment: Type of value has a mismatch with column typeCouldn't store <C:\Users\Max\Pictures\2010-02-07\001.JPG> in File_Path Column.  Expected type is Byte[].this is the error i now get after changing the field to OLE

Comment: @Joshua Hornby: Please visit link in my answer. This link explains it how to save image in MS Access. It has all required code as well.